# Calculating the number of remaining items in a list from a given index

Tags: python

I appolgise for such a newb question but....

If I have a list:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

and I want to know how many items are left after a given index , what is the most pythonic way of doing this? The best I can come up with is

```
remainder = len(my_list[index:])-1
```

or even worse:

```
remainder = (len(my_list) - index) -1
```

In the first example I have to add the magic number 1 because the slice is inclusive, in the second one I have to use the magic number 1 to correct for the fact that the index is zero based and the length is not! I am sure there is a simpler and more pythonic way of doing this, and equally that I am going to kick myself when I see it!

Comment: Both of your method are fine.

Comment: so there isn't any way of doing this without using a magic number?

Comment: I think the above methods are pretty much the only way to do it (and they seem fine to me -- I would prefer the second as it doesn't create an intermediate list).  I think a better question is *WHY* do you want this information as opposed to just slicing the list and using that naturally?

Comment: The second one is OK. The first one creates a slice object only needed for its length. It may be not that slow, but still redundant.

Comment: If you don't like magic numbers then you can declare a variable with value of 1.

Comment: Good point, fair enough, this was mostly a sanity check, and I agree wt=ith @mgilson that it would be better to slice and use it naturally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the second one is fine:

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> length=len(my_list)
>>> index=2
>>> length-(index+1)  #remaining elements are [4,5,6,7]
4
>>> index=4
>>> length-(index+1)  #remaining elements are [6,7]
2
```

`Timeit` results, proves second one is faster than the first one with slicing:

```
import random
def func1():
    lis=list(xrange(100))
    for i in xrange(100):
        index=random.randrange(0,100)
        remainder = len(lis[index:])-1
def func2():
    lis=list(xrange(100))
    for i in xrange(100):
        index=random.randrange(0,100)
        remainder = (len(lis) - index) -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    t = Timer("func2()", "from __main__ import func2")
    print t.timeit()    
    t = Timer("func1()", "from __main__ import func1")
    print t.timeit()
```

**output:**

```
47.001240015
52.2959749699
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most Pythonic option is:

```
len(my_list[index+1:])
```

Since this portrays the correct *meaning* of what you want to calculate.

Comment: @Ctrlspc sorry I initially read it as "left of", rather than "left after", my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Slices are complementary to `range` (`xrange` in Python 2):

```
len(range(index + 1, len(my_list)))
```

gives you the length of `my_list[index + 1:]`.

More accurately (to allow for e.g. a negative end index) you can use:

```
len(range(*slice(index + 1, None).indices(len(my_list))))
```

NumPy has the elegant `s_` object to convert slice indexing to slice objects:

```
import numpy as np
len(range(*np.s_[index + 1:].indices(len(my_list))))
```